# Creating Variable at runtime in python

Tags: python

Just out of curiosity it is possible to create a variable name in runtime in python.
Similar to

```
for i in range(5):
    varname_+str(i) = i*4
```

I am quit sure it is not possible is `java` and `c++` but python is changing rapidly so I think it might have been introduced. Although I didn't find any reference.
`NOTE :` Don't ask me to use `map/dict` I know they can be used in such case as they will exhibit same behavior. But I just wanted to confirm if it is possible. 
I also wanted to know why it is not incorporated. It will make things fun may be sometime cause issue with code readability.
It will be great if you can give some reference with your answer.

Comment: Yes, just assign to whatever name you like `foo = 5`

Comment: I didn't get it. Like if I want to create foo_{} = 5. How can I do it. Where I can assign any value. through run time like using format?

Comment: In CPython, this is possible only for the glbal scope, using, e.g. `exec` or modifying  the `globals()` dict directly (global namespaces are actually just `dict` objecs). It does not work in local scopes

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga can you provide me where exactly to look for some ref. Cause I am not sure what exactly to query in google as well

Comment: Here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec